# Using a specific version of Saxon in Orbeon

Tags: orbeon

Is it possible to use a specific version of Saxon in Orbeon, i.e. bypass using the built in version and use Saxon-HE or Saxon-EE?
How would I go about doing this?

There are some old forum posts from 2010 suggesting that this is possible, but the links within it are now dead.

Comment: For XSLT transformations, or the XPath processor used by XForms?

Comment: For XSLT Transformations. 
My apologies, the wider scenario is this - I am actually trying to see if it is possible to upgrade an old version of Orbeon and implement a specific version of Saxon - the application uses XML pipelines (xpl), which are no longer under development from what I understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For XSLT transformations only, this is possible, although at this point it's not really documented or encouraged.

In `WEB-INF/resources/config/processors-local.xml`, set:

```
<processors xmlns:oxf="http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/processors">

    <processor name="oxf:my-saxon">
        <instantiation name="oxf:generic-xslt-2.0">
            <input name="transformer">
                <config>
                    <class>net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl</class>
                </config>
            </input>
            <input name="attributes">
                <attributes xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
                    <!-- By default, prevent usage of external functions for security purposes -->
                    <attribute as="xs:boolean" name="http://saxon.sf.net/feature/allow-external-functions" value="false"/>
                    <!--
                    <attribute as="xs:boolean" name="http://saxon.sf.net/feature/trace-external-functions" value="false"/>
                    <attribute as="xs:boolean" name="http://saxon.sf.net/feature/timing" value="false"/>
                    <attribute as="xs:integer" name="http://saxon.sf.net/feature/treeModel" value="STANDARD_TREE = 0 / TINY_TREE = 1"/>
                    <attribute as="xs:boolean" name="http://saxon.sf.net/feature/linenumbering" value="false"/>
                    <attribute as="xs:integer" name="http://saxon.sf.net/feature/recoveryPolicy" value="RECOVER_SILENTLY = 0 / RECOVER_WITH_WARNINGS = 1 / DO_NOT_RECOVER = 2"/>
                    <attribute as="xs:boolean" name="http://saxon.sf.net/feature/validation" value="false"/>
                    <attribute as="xs:boolean" name="http://saxon.sf.net/feature/schema-validation" value="false"/>
                    <attribute as="xs:boolean" name="http://saxon.sf.net/feature/validation-warnings" value="false"/>
                    -->
                </attributes>
            </input>
        </instantiation>
    </processor>

</processors>
```

Also place your Saxon JAR in `WEB-INF/lib`, of course.

Then, when using the processor, you should use `oxf:my-saxon` (but pick a better name).